# How to count date difference in vb.net and count saturday and sunday as 1?

Tags: vb.net

I am new to programming and I want to learn.

I am counting the date difference from the date of check postponement to the actual check date. (Accounting Scenario)

Let say, I have a check which is dated "Aug. 20, 2019", I want to postpone my check today which is "Aug. 16, 2019". By counting the date from today to the check date, the date difference is 4 days, which will allow  me to postpone my check since the allowed day allocation for postponement of check is 4 days later than the postponement date,

The problem is, Saturday and Sunday is counted as 1 and if the following day which is Monday is a Holiday, then Saturday, Sunday and Monday will be counted also as 1 for date difference.

***IF Monday is a holiday:***
*From "Aug. 16 2019" to "Aug. 20 2019" has only 3 days date difference since "Aug. 17" and "Aug. 18" are saturday and sunday which will be counted as 1*

***IF Monday is not a holiday***
*From "Aug. 16 2019" to "Aug. 20 2019" has only 2 days date difference since "Aug. 17", "Aug. 18" and "Aug. 19" are saturday, sunday and a holiday which will be counted as 1*

> Note: Holidays are saved and retrieved from the database. and I don't know how to integrate holidays in my code.

I have tried this but my code only count the range of days one by one. I want it to count Saturday and Sunday as 1 and if the follwing day is a holiday, then count it as 1.

Datagridview shows the list of my dated check and I loop through it to check:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1

    Dim checkdate As DateTime = Format(CDate(dgv("OldDepositDate", i).Value))

    If checkdate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(4) Then
        MessageBox.Show(checkdate & " Ok for postponement")

    ElseIf checkdate <= DateTime.Now Then
        MessageBox.Show(checkdate & " Override")
    End If
Next
```

I expect the output of 2 days, but the actual output is 4.

My Co-worker give the old query script to me that was formerly used but this one is so advance or somehow very complicated,

If somebody can explain this to me, I appreciate a lot:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, number, Cast(getDate() as Date)) [Date],
     1 IsWorkDay,
     1 IsWeekDay
     INTO #TMP
    FROM Master..spt_values WHERE [Type] = 'P'

     UPDATE A SET A.IsWorkDay = 0 FROM Master..#TMP A INNER JOIN AMIFIN..HOLIDAYS B ON A.Date = B.Date 

     UPDATE Master..#TMP SET IsWeekDay = 0, IsWorkDay = 0 WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [Date]) IN (1, 7)

    SET @CheckDate = ()     
    SELECT  
         T.Check_No as CheckNo, T.Check_Date as CDate
    FROM AMIFIN..PDC T 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.#TMP c 
        ON c.[Date] >= getDate() AND c.[Date] <= T.Check_Date  AND c.IsWorkDay = 1 
        WHERE T.PN_No <> '' AND T.[PDC Status] <> 'Pulled Out'
        GROUP BY T.Check_Date, T.Check_No, T.Check_Date HAVING COUNT(c.[Date]) >= 3
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: As with any programming problem, you should start by forgetting that it is a programming problem. Pick up a pen and paper and work out how you would perform the task manually. Once you can do it manually, write out the steps you need to perform formally. That's your algorithm. Now, the programming part is simply implementing the algorithm in code. If you don't have an algorithm then you don;t know what your code has to do, so how could you write it? If you do have an algorithm then you always have something to compare your code to for correctness.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I did write down all the possible solution, but im struggling.

Comment: If you have an algorithm but the code you implement it with doesn't behave as expected, you need to specify the algorithm, the code and exactly where and how the behaviour of the code differs from your expectation.  That doesn't just mean the result but the specific step and the data in use at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the difference in days normally

```
DateTime a = new DateTime(2019, 2, 25);
DateTime b = new DateTime(2019, 6, 3);
int days = (b-a).Days; // DateTime - DateTime = TimeSpan
```

Then calculate the amount of weeks

```
int weeks = days / 7; // if you have 4 days from friday to tuesday, this will give you 0 though.
int weekendCount = weeks;
if (a.DayOfWeek > b.DayOfWeek) { weekendCount ++; } // correct for this fault by adding 1 if not a whole week has passed.
// This might not be enough, depending on how you want to handle a saturday to sunday transition.
```

Now subtract the amount of weekends from the amount of days.

```
int daysButWeekendsCountAsOneDay = days - weekendCount;
```

No idea how to handle your holidays though. I don't think .Net has anything for that, especially since there are many different ones in different countries and even regions of countries.
In that case you probably want some kind of library and just loop over all the days up until your target date and count up with lots of condition checking, which would be very slow, especially for big date differences.

**Edit**

With a quick search i have found [this library](https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.Date) which can be used to check for holidays.

Using this you could compile a list of weekend days and holidays in the years between your start and end date, then go through that list and check for every item if it is between the two and if it is also following another holidays/weekend days. if so, subtract one from your amount of days.
This would be faster than looping over every single day.

Comment: @jzoler that's a different question. maybe you should ask your co-worker about his query.

Comment: He doesnt even know how the query behaves. He just told me to recycle those old stuff. It seems to be somthing like comparing dates and holidays, but thanks by the way.